# Which is right? typeorm nullable lazy relation

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm

For typeorm with ts, when writing an entity with nullable lazy relation, have a question that which way to write it is right, to put undefined into result type, or put it outside (make the property optional):

```
@Entity('a')
export class A{
  ...

  @OneToOne('B', { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'b_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  b?: Promise<B>;
}
```

```
@Entity('a')
export class A{
  ...

  @OneToOne('B', { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'b_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  b: Promise<B | undefined>;
}
```